# How to use tree data in antd nested tables?

Tags: reactjs, antd, dvajs

I'm trying to put tree data in antd nested tables，but it always renders empty rows  when I clicked the expand button.

Can I use tree data in nested tables and how?And why it happened?

[code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qiantaozibiaoge-antd4102-forked-zxwgy?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two problems here.

1. `children` property will always render its data source in the same table set with parent. You seems to want to render some expandable data  which depends on the `children` property, so the table set will render both the expanded table defined by you and the children data source.
2. You have not prevented node expansion which are doesn't contain children. Before defining the `rowexpandable` handler, all nodes are expandable by default whether their children is empty or not.

My solution is to rename the `children` property to prevent children data source rendering and to define a `rowexpandable` handler to prevent empty children to be expanded.

expamle:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/qiantaozibiaoge-antd4102-forked-6b0x4?file=/index.js:2194-2207

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer completely resolved my question! But there still one row I can't understand ,what's the usage of  '?.' in `(record) => record?.childNodes?.length`?Does it is conditional operator？I've tried to google it but no result.

Comment: The keyword is "optional chaining".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining